# How to find out what is initiating an (re)render in React

Tags: reactjs

How can you trace what action, state change or dom manipulation is initiating a (re)render?

I'm using TransitionGroup to animate with JS, however before the callback of componentWillLeave(callback) is called, the page re-renders and I have no idea why. What kind can initiate a full page rerender beside forceUpdate() and state change of the top level component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the lifecycle method [`componentWillUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillupdate) which fires just before a component is re-rendered due to a change in props or state:

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  // Inspect nextProps and nextState to see what triggered this
}
```